# sed single quotes

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I've been banging into escaping single quote's problem using SED (Bash shell).

I need to make

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

into

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword';
```

What I've tried is:

```
sed -i "s/$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';/$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '$rootpassword';/g" /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.bak
```

Which ends up really jumbling the line.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password['Servers'][]['passsword'] = 'mypassword'
```

I've tried the '\'' to escape single quotes and I think everything else under the sun but just can't get it quite there.

can anyone point to my probable obvious mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that the only line with `''` on it? if so, just match on that. Also, add the `-r` flag for extended-regex. This will solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Be mindful of the other literals - `$`, `[`, `]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -i "s/\$cfg\['Servers'\]\[\$i\]\['password'\] = '';/\$cfg['Servers'][\$i]['password'] = '\$rootpassword';/g" file
```

Comment: this worked - just had to add an extra \ infront of $rootpassword.

I guess I need to read up more on escaping.  I think I'm getting hung up on why somethings escaped.  i.e. why `[\$i]` in one spot vs `\[\$i\]` in another.

Answer (score 13):

instead of escaping, you can use `\x27` for single quote. this works not only for sed, for awk etc. as well.

see test:

```
kent$  cat tt
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''

kent$  sed -r 's/(\$cfg\[\x27Servers\x27\]\[\$i\]\[\x27password\x27\] \= \x27)\x27/\1mypassword\x27/g' tt
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword'
```

note that, the sed line may not be the best solution for your problem, e.g. put the whole string to "s/../" may not be necessary. However, I just want to show how the \x27 worked.

Comment: that worked cool as heck.  no fun to read but it worked.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: you can also use `'\''` too within a single quoted command. Just punches a hole though to shell where `\'` quotes a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i "/Servers.*password.*''$/s/''/'foo'/" /path/to/your/testfile
```

Match a line that contains "anything..Servers..anything..password..anything..''" (end with `''`) and on that line replace `''` with `'foo'`

This can match more than one lines, but *only the first* occurance will be changed. 
Test it, it's most probable that `.. Servers .. password .. ''` is only on one line.

Or you can just escape everything.

Comment: interesting, looks like that would match two lines, Servers .. password and Servers .. nopassword.

but - the one I need is the first instance.  not bad for a fallback plan if needed